# Understanding the Eötvös experiment

Tags: classical-mechanics, experimental-physics

The aim of the Eötvös experiment was to "prove" that for every (massive) particle, the quotient $\frac{m_g}{m_i}$ is constant, where $m_g$ is the gravitational mass and $m_i$ is the inertial mass.

**The experiment:**

Consider two objects with coordinates $x(t)$, $y(t)$  and with masses $M_i$, $M_g$, $m_i$, $m_g$  (on the earth where the gravitational field $\mathbf g$ can be considered constant), 
connected by a rod of length $r$, and suspended in a horizontal orientation by a fine wire. The  Newton's second law says that
$$\ddot {\mathbf{x}}(t)=-\frac{M_g}{M_i}\mathbf g$$
$$\ddot {\mathbf{y}}(t)=-\frac{m_g}{m_i}\mathbf g$$
so if we experiment that the quantity $\eta:=\frac{2|\ddot {\mathbf x}(t)-\ddot{\mathbf  y}(t)|} {|\ddot {\mathbf x}(t)+\ddot{\mathbf  y}(t)|}$ is very small, then when can conclude that $\frac{M_g}{M_i}=\frac{m_g}{m_i}$ and so we are done. Now textbooks say that if $\ddot {\mathbf{x}}(t)\neq\ddot {\mathbf{y}}(t)$ then we will have a torque

$$N=\eta\, r(\mathbf g\times \mathbf{e_2})\cdot \mathbf{e_1}$$

and misuring this torque we can give an estimation of $\eta$.

[image]

**My problem:**

Even if the two accelerations are different, I don't understand where is the torque, the point ${\mathbf{x}}(t)$ will move down and ${\mathbf{y}}(t)$ will move up in my opinion. The angular momentum is along $\mathbf{e_3}$, so the rotation is in the plane $\left<\mathbf{e_1},\mathbf{e_2}\right>$.

Comment: You also need a centrifugal force, from the Earth's rotation...

Comment: And why? I'm testing free falling motions.

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia article on this? Your diagram is missing forces critical to the experiment.

Comment: Free falling motions?  These are far from freefall... the effect is only observable in the presence of external forces...

Comment: So if we had different gravitational accelerations, by composing them with the (equal) centrifugal accelerations, we would see a torque...

Comment: Isn't $\bf{g}\times\bf{e}_2 = 0$ in the drawing above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The torque about $\bf{e}_3$ is zero when the masses weights are balanced on the rod. For example the distance from $M$ to the support must be equal to $c = \frac{m_g}{M_g+m_g} r$

There is torque about $\bf{e}_2$ if the centrifugal forces are not propotional to the weights.

$$ \tau_2 = M_i c \ddot{x}_3 - m_i (r-c) \ddot{y}_3 $$ where $\ddot{x}_3$, $\ddot{y}_3$  are the observed accelerations in the $\bf{e}_3$ direction. Combining the torque the balance equation above gives

$$ \tau_2 = r \left( \frac{M_i m_g}{M_g +m_g} \ddot{x}_3 - \frac{M_g m_i}{M_g+m_g} \ddot{y}_3 \right) $$

which is obviously zero when $\boxed{\frac{M_i}{M_g} = \frac{m_i}{m_g}} $ and $\ddot{x}_3 = \frac{M_g}{M_i} g$, $\ddot{y}_3 = \frac{m_g}{m_i} g$.